# How do I pass only a multiprocessing.Array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

When using multiprocessing, why does this, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), work...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

But this variation,

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array   

def f(a):
        for i in range(len(a)):
            a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(arr[:])
```

produces a TypeError?

```
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 10 were given
```

How do I pass just the array to the function?

Comment: `(num, arr)` is a tuple with two elements.  `(arr)` isn't a tuple, it's the same thing as just `arr`.  To make it a tuple with one element, you need to write `(arr,)`.

Answer (score 0):

So a small change in how the array is passed fixed the problem but I would still like to know why it has to be done like this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('i', 10)
    print(arr[:])

    p = Process(target=f, args=([arr]))  # Note the [] arround arr
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(arr[:])
```